# FFMPEG how do i remove png and blur from this code

Tags: ffmpeg

how do i remove the 55.png code and blur.

```
ffmpeg -y -i 55.mp4 -i "55.png" -i "intro.mp4" -filter_complex "[0:a]atempo=1.15,volume=1.6,pan=stereo|c0<c0+0*c1|c1<c0+0*c1,aeval=val(0)|-val(1) [amain]; [0:v]setpts=PTS/1.15,crop=iw/1.2:ih/1.2,boxblur=1:2,scale=1280:720,setdar=16/9 [v1]; [v1][1:v]overlay=0:0 [vmain]; [2:v]scale=1280:720,setdar=16/9 [vintro]; [vintro][2:a][vmain][amain]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 1400k -profile:v main -level 3.1 -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -metadata title="" -metadata artist="" -metadata album_artist="" -metadata album="" -metadata date="" -metadata track="" -metadata genre="" -metadata publisher="" -metadata encoded_by="" -metadata copyright="" -metadata composer="" -metadata performer="" -metadata TIT1="" -metadata TIT3="" -metadata disc="" -metadata TKEY="" -metadata TBPM="" -metadata language="eng" -metadata encoder="" -bufsize 500000k -threads 0 -preset superfast out2222.mp4
```

will really appreciate it if you can show me how to remove the Blur and 55.png Code Overlay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command with `55.png`, overlay, and boxblur removed:

```
ffmpeg -y -i 55.mp4 -i "intro.mp4" -filter_complex "[0:a]atempo=1.15,volume=1.6,pan=stereo|c0<c0+0*c1|c1<c0+0*c1,aeval=val(0)|-val(1) [amain]; [0:v]setpts=PTS/1.15,crop=iw/1.2:ih/1.2,scale=1280:720,setdar=16/9 [vmain]; [1:v]scale=1280:720,setdar=16/9 [vintro]; [vintro][1:a][vmain][amain]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1" -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -r 30 -g 60 -b:v 1400k -profile:v main -level 3.1 -acodec libmp3lame -b:a 128k -ar 44100 -metadata title="" -metadata artist="" -metadata album_artist="" -metadata album="" -metadata date="" -metadata track="" -metadata genre="" -metadata publisher="" -metadata encoded_by="" -metadata copyright="" -metadata composer="" -metadata performer="" -metadata TIT1="" -metadata TIT3="" -metadata disc="" -metadata TKEY="" -metadata TBPM="" -metadata language="eng" -metadata encoder="" -bufsize 500000k -threads 0 -preset superfast out2222.mp4
```

Comment: Excellent boss just what i was trying to do very nice. i also have another question i will update post 1.

Comment: @das You should post a new question for this.

Comment: ok thank you hope nobody Minuses my post like they normally do lol please check new post https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/29971/ffmpeg-creating-a-5-second-clip-from-single-png-and-compile